# How to match a list of values from Database1 with a column in Database2 using JDBC Request in JMeter?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, jmeter

I am quite new to JMeter, so I am looking for the best approach to do this: I want to get a list of messageID's from Database1 and then check whether these messageID values will be found in Database2 and then check the ErrorMessage column for these ID's against what I expect.

I have the JDBC Request working for extracting the list of messageID's from Database1. JMeter returns the list to me, but now I'm stuck. I am not sure how to handle the variable names and result variable names field in the JDBC Request and use this in the next throughput controller loop for the JDBC Request for Database2.

My JDBC request looks like this (PostgreSQL):

```
 SELECT messageID FROM database1

 ORDER BY created DESC

 FETCH FIRST 20 ROWS ONLY
```

Variable names: messageid
Result variable names: resultDB1

Then I use the BeanShell Assertion to see whether the connection to the database is present, or whether the response is empty.

But now, I have to connect to a different database, so I need to make a new throughput controller with a new JDBC configuration, Request, etc in there, but I don't know how to pass on the messageid list to this new request.

What I thought about was writing the list of results from Database1 into a file and then read the values from that file for Database2, but that seems like unnecessarily complicated to me, like there should be a solution in JMeter already for that. Also, I am running my JMeter tests on a remote linux server, so I don't want to make it more complicated by making new files and saving them somewhere.

Comment: I think you are confusing "database" with "table" here. After a `from` you can't have a database name, only a table name

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your `resultDB1` into a JMeter Property like:

```
props.put("resultDB1", vars.getObject("resultDB1"));
```

As per [JMeter Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

> Properties are not the same as variables. Variables are local to a thread; properties are common to all threads

So basically JMeter Properties is a subset of Java [Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) which are global for the whole JVM

Once done you will be able to access the value in other [Thread Groups](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) like:

```
ArrayList resultDB1 = (ArrayList)props.get("resultDB1");
ArrayList resultDB2 = (ArrayList)vars.getObject("resultDB2");
//your code to compare 2 result sets here
```

Also be aware that [since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider migrating to [JSR223 Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial) on next available opportunity.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I tried to put the JSR223 PostProcessor in the first throughput controller with the code you suggested, then used it in the second throughput controller loop to check with the next database. However, now the PSQL request looks like this after running the script:

[Select Statement] select * from database1.table
where messageid like '[{messageid=1234567}]';

While it should be just 1234567 without the 'messageid=' in front of it. I stored the result as an object in the JDBC Request. If I store it as a String it doesn't work either. What am I doing wrong?